# How to show that if $A\mathbin{\triangle}C=B\mathbin{\triangle}C$ for all $C$, then $A=B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have no idea how to start the proof.

$\triangle$ means the symmetric difference.

Prove or Disprove the following:

For every 2 sets $A$ and $B$
if for every $C$

$A \mathbin{\triangle} C = B \mathbin{\triangle} C $

then 
$A=B$

Comment: I held an office hour today. I'm also available on email. (For what it's worth, it's fine that you ask here.)

Comment: @Brian: For binary operators, use `\mathbin` rather than `\mathrel`.

Comment: @Asaf: Did I use `\mathrel`? Damn, I did. Fixing it now.

Comment: @Brian: And none but the truly $\rm\LaTeX$-sensitive eyes will know the difference! :)

Comment: @Asaf: We’ll just have to call you *Micrometer-Eyes*!

Comment: @Brian: [Apparently, I hate myself](http://xkcd.com/1015/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the set $A \mathbin{\triangle} C$ is defined to be the set of all elements that belong to either $A$ or $C$ but not both.
Notice that if we take $C$ to be the empty set then $A \mathbin{\triangle} C=A$.

Therefore, you can prove the statement by just taking $C$ to be the empty set.

It might be worth noting that a more general result is true. That is, if there exists some set $C$ such that $$A\mathbin{\triangle} C = B\mathbin{\triangle} C$$ then $$A=B$$

Proof: Suppose $a\in A$. There are two cases to consider.

Case 1: If $a\in C$, then $a\notin A \mathbin{\triangle} C$ since $a$ lies in both $A$ and $C$. So $a\notin B \mathbin{\triangle} C$, whence $a\in B$.

Case 2: If $a\notin C$, then $a\in A \mathbin{\triangle} C$ since $a$ lies in $A$ but not $C$. So $a\in B \mathbin{\triangle} C$, whence $a\in B$.

So we have shown that any element of $A$ lies in $B$. Similarly, one can show that any element of $B$ lies in $A$. Therefore, $A=B$. $\square$

Comment: I apologize if the question was somehow stupid or inappropriate,

Comment: (+1) A shorter proof is possible if one already has the associative law for symmetric difference: $$A=A\mathrel{\triangle}\varnothing=A\mathrel{\triangle}(C\mathrel{\triangle}C)= (A\mathrel{\triangle}C)\mathrel{\triangle}C=(B\mathbin{\triangle}C)\mathbin{\triangle}C=B\mathbin{\triangle}(C\mathbin{\triangle}C)=B\mathbin{\triangle}\varnothing =B$$ Also, it may be that $A\mathbin{\triangle}B$ was defined as $(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$ rather than as $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

Comment: @d.hk: The question is not stupid, nor it is inappropriate. Taking the first steps in writing proofs is usually a nontrivial mental process.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that if you are given the assumption that "For every $x$ such and such happens", you are free to place whatever $x$ into the equation.

This is very similar, and in fact a specific case,<sup>1</sup> of the statement that if $\Bbb F$ is a field, and for every $c$, $a+c=b+c$, then $a=b$. How would you have solved that? You would have argued that since this equation is true for *every* $c$, in particular it is true for $c=0$, and in that case we get $a=a+0=b+0=b$, so $a=b$.

Here we have a similar situation, where taking $C=\varnothing$ solves the problem in a similar fashion. You are, however, expected to argue why $A\mathbin{\triangle}\varnothing=A$, for an arbitrary set $A$.

---

1. This is a specific case, since $\mathcal P(X)$ along with $\triangle$ and $\cap$ form a *field* where $\triangle$ gives us $+$ and $\cap$ gives $\cdot$; so $A\mathbin{\triangle}\varnothing$ is the same as $A+0$.

Comment: Is the closure of X under the powerset operation a field?